# Nginx prefix/subdirectory

Tags: nginx, docker, glpi

What is happening is that the GLPI project is not loading the files (js, css, php, etc).

The local URL is `http://localhost/glpi-grupo/`, but all the files in Elements are missin the `/glpi-grupo` like this: `http://localhost/style.css`

[image]

I need to force them to load with the subdirectory `/glpi-grupo`

I'm using Nginx and Traefik, all in a Docker container.

My traefik rule:

```
traefik.frontend.rule: Host:localhost; PathPrefixStrip:/glpi-grupo
```

My Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/html;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $host;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_pass glpi-grupo:9000;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to fix your application configuration's base URL so that it generates correct URLs.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The application it to big. It is a open source project called GLPI

Comment: So have you checked if the application has configuration for this?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I had checked, but there is no config variable for this... to make it works, i will need change the entire code.